# Skryim crashes on startup

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

So when I start skyrim, it loads up to the point of the actual world being there for a split second, then the game closes. I can see my weapon, the room I'm in, and everything else that would be there when the game loads. But then immediately afterwards, the game just closes. no warning, alert anything. Just back to desktop.

Here's a video

Comment: How did you install it?  What mods do you have?  We need quite a bit more information before we can help.

Comment: I don't have any mods at all, I installed it with steam. I've restarted my computer.

Comment: Try to load an earlier save and see if that also crashes. Also try to do an integrity check on the game in steam: Right click Skyrim -> Properties -> Local Files -> Verify integrity of game files

Comment: I guess that really was all it was wasn't it? insteresting, yesterday I played and left the blue plalace. I crashed. everytime I laoded that save it would crash. Now i can do the same thing and it's fine